# "The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing." In Closed XML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, closedxml

I am using the [closed XML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) for generating the excel template. After filling the data in the generated excel, I am trying to import the excel with data. It returns error "The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing." . I am using XLSX file.

```
try
 {
      var   workbook = new XLWorkbook(FILE_PATH);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{   
         throw;
}
```

It throws error when creating object of XLWOrkbook using the excel template generated.

Please provide a solution,

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

I got the issue. My file was in the format "**Strict Open XML Spreadsheet**". I have changed into "**Excel Workbook**". It might be useful for you.

Comment: Should set as accepted answer, it helped _me_.